# Pagination not working - on click event page goes back the first page

Tags: html, angular, asp.net-core, pagination

Hi I was trying to implement pagination in my movies list.
The API is working and the ngx-bootstrap pagination is also working.
When I try to implement the PageChanged event, and I click on the next page number, it just comes back to the first page.
I am using angular 10

My HTML file

```
<div *ngFor="let tblmovie of tblmovies | filter:search" class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
<div class=' bg-black dib br1 pa1   ma2 grow bw2 shadow-5 item' style="max-width:230px; max-height:380px ;overflow:hidden; border: blanchedalmond;">
<a [routerLink]="['/movies',tblmovie.aMovieId]" ><img class="border border-white" width=230px height=300px alt='movieImage'   src = {{tblmovie.aImageLink}}/></a>
<div  class="text-center">
   <h6 max-width=200px max-height=320px style="color:white; overflow: hidden;">{{tblmovie.aTitle}}</h6>
   <p  style="color:white;">{{tblmovie.aPrice}}$
      {{tblmovie.aPurchasePrice}}$ 
      {{tblmovie.aRating}}⭐
   </p>
</div>
</div
```

and the ngx-pagination module

```
  <pagination [boundaryLinks]="true" [totalItems]="pagination.totalItems"
              [itemsPerPage]="pagination.itemsPerPage"
              [(ngModel)]="pagination.currentPage"
              (pageChanged)="pageChanged($event)"
              previousText="&lsaquo;" nextText="&rsaquo;" firstText="&laquo;" lastText="&raquo;">
</pagination>
```

As of now my output is
[Console Output with page numbers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJBAx.png)

[The webpage output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jf43Z.jpg)

My .ts file:

```
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->

<!-- language: lang-js -->

import { HttpClient, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Movie } from '../_models/movie';
import { PaginatedResult, Pagination } from '../_models/pagination';
import { AlertifyService } from '../_services/alertify.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tblmovie',
  templateUrl: './tblmovie.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tblmovie.component.css']
})
export class TblmovieComponent implements OnInit {
  tblmovies: any;
  pagination: Pagination;
  //  pageNumber=1;
  //  pageSize=8;
   movieParams: any={};
  
  search;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient,private alertify:AlertifyService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getValues();
    this.movieParams.orderBy= 'rating';
  }

  pageChanged(event: any): void {
    this.pagination.currentPage = event.page;
    console.log(this.pagination.currentPage);
    this.getValues(this.pagination.currentPage,this.pagination.itemsPerPage);
  }

  getValues(page?,itemsPerPage?){
    const paginatedResult: PaginatedResult<any> = new PaginatedResult<any>();
    let params = new HttpParams();
    if(page!=null && itemsPerPage!=null){
      params=params.append('pageNumber',page);
      params=params.append('pageSize',itemsPerPage);
    }
    if(this.movieParams!=null){
      params = params.append('orderBy',this.movieParams.orderBy);
    }
    this.http.get('http://localhost:5000/api/movies',{observe: 'response',params}).pipe(
      map(response =>{
        paginatedResult.result = response.body;
        if(response.headers.get('Pagination') != null){
          paginatedResult.pagination = JSON.parse(response.headers.get('Pagination'));
        }
        return paginatedResult;
      })
    ).subscribe((response : PaginatedResult<any>) => {
      this.tblmovies = response.result;
      this.pagination = response.pagination;
    }, error =>{
      this.alertify.error(error);
    });
  }
}


<!--end snippet -->
```

when I click the next page arrow, it comes back to the first page.
How do I implement pagination without the component breaking

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your HTML to the following:

```
<pagination [boundaryLinks]="true" [totalItems]="pagination?.totalItems"
          previousText="&lsaquo;" nextText="&rsaquo;" firstText="&laquo;" lastText="&raquo;">
```

Since you are declaring the `pagination` property in the following manner:

```
pagination: Pagination;
```

and not giving it a default value, `pagination.totalItems` will likely be throwing a console error saying `cannot read 'totalItems' of undefined`. Adding the "?" i.e. `pagination?.totalItems` tells the browser that `pagination` may be null or undefined, meaning `undefined` will get passed in as the value for `totalItems`, as opposed to a console error which is likely breaking your pagination component.

Comment: Robert, I got that fixed, I edited the question now. When I click the next page arrow  or the number, it doesn't go there. Thanks for the response

Comment: Also, how do i add "?" to the [ngModel]="pagination.currentPage" as adding a '?' is giving out an error

Comment: In that case you'll want to initialise `pagination` with a default value. You could use `currentPage: 0` to start with. 

`pagination = { currentPage: 0 }` (add other default properties where required)